# docker-compose build not uses latest code

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I noticed that when I build and run Docker container ASP.NET Core application using Visual Studio, the latest code are used. While, if I run docker-compose build the latest code are not used. I need to build all the solution before running docker-compose build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try building the images using:

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Then run:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

This will build images without using cache and then force new containers to start using the newest images.